"If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area"

$p$ : Grizzly bears have been seen in the area.
$q$ : Hiking is safe on the trail.
$r$ : Berries are ripe along the trail.
If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe if and only if
grizzly bears have not been seen in the area.

I came up with the translation $r→(q↔¬p).\tag*{}$ But multiple sources and the official solution are giving $(r→ q)↔¬p.\tag*{}$ Could someone please explain whether these two are logically equivalent or not? And if they are not logically equivalent, then how to figure out where to put the parenthesis? Does the word "then" make the difference here?

I believe it's a grammatical error in the initial question. Your answer is correct given what is written. The other answer is correct if it was written more along the lines of "If berries are ripe along the trail, then hiking is safe, if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area."

@Joseph_Kopp considering there are no grammatical errors, could you please explain how I would understand where to put the parenthesis? does the word "then" make the difference here? also, I checked from multiple sources, the other answer is apparently the correct one. thank you very much for your response though.

In my opinion, your solution is correct and also just makes more sense when thinking about the world.

There's some ambiguity in how what is being said in english should/can be interpreted.  Like you, I interpreted it as "when berries are ripe along the trail... under that circumstance, then hiking is safe if and only if bears haven't been seen". Others are interpreting it as "Ripe berries or an indication of the safety of hiking, when (and only when Bears have not been seen [if bears have been seen then berries are not an indication of hiking safety]".  I guess theres nothing in english grammar to indicate one over the other.

They are certainly NOT equivalent.   $r\implies (q\iff \lnot p)$ means... Given the case that berries are ripe along the trail, we can claim hiking is safe if and only if bears haven't been seen. $(r\implies q)\iff \lnot p$ means... ripe berries are an indication that hiking is safe, if and only if bears haven't been seen.  English grammar is ambiguous what they mean. However "common sense" makes me think the former is the more natural and sensical way to interpret it.

Mathematical logic is not supposed to imply causality and we are not supposed to use "common sense". Using only english grammar this is ambiguous as to whether they mean "If berries are ripe along the trail, (hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area)" ($r\implies (q\iff \lnot p)$) or "(If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe) if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area" ($(r\implies q)\iff \lnot p$. The problem is if we try to apply "common sense" neither show the whole picture... to be cont.

If we take $(r\implies q)\iff \lnot p$.  That means if bears have been seen then then $r\implies q$ is false. The only way that can be false if if $r$ to and $q$ is false.... so seeing bears magically forces $r$ to be true, and if bears are seen berries must be ripe on the trail???? But $r\implies (q \iff \lnot p)$ has similar oddity. If no bears are seen and berries are ripe hiking is impossible of being unsafe??? But if berries aren't ripe and no bears are seen hiking can be unsafe?  All in all I'm still going with your interpretation but... it's arbitrary.

@fleablood An exercise in translation (formalising a natural-language statement) is about faithfulness rather than factuality. A pertinent question is: should we translate what the author is trying to say, or what they are actually saying? I think it depends on the situation.



$p$ : Grizzly bears have been seen in the area.
$q$ : Hiking is safe on the trail.
$r$ : Berries are ripe along the trail.

I came up with the translation $r→(q↔¬p).\tag1$ But multiple sources and the
official solution are giving $(r→ q)↔¬p.\tag2$

Statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ attain opposite truth values under the interpretation ($p,q,r$)=(T,F,F), so aren't equivalent to each other.
This being a translation exercise, we disregard the fact that $(1)$ is more common-sensical than $(2).$


If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe if and only if
grizzly bears have not been seen in the area.


Without a comma before "if and only if", the given natural-language statement reads much more naturally as statement $(1).$ However, it's arguably ambiguous between statements $(1)$ and $(2):$

If berries are ripe along the trail, (hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area)
✔️ If berries are ripe along the trail, then hiking being safe is equivalent to grizzly bears not having been seen in the area

(If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe) if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area
✔️ Hiking is safe if berries are ripe along the trail, if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area
✔️ Grizzly bears have not been seen in the area if and only if if berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe
✔️ These two statements are equivalent: grizzly bears have not been seen in the area, and hiking is safe if berries are ripe along the trail.


Noting that $$(p→ r)∧ (\boldsymbol{r→(q↔¬p)})  \quad\equiv\quad \boldsymbol{(r→q)↔¬p},$$ statement $(1)$ is logically weaker (says less) than statement $(2),$ and the author's intended reading is statement $(2)$ if and only if they mean to additionally say that grizzlies being seen implies ripe berries.

Does the word "then" make the difference here?

Sometimes we can utilise the word "then" to tacitly create disambiguating parentheses. Unfortunately, this doesn't apply here, and the given statement remains ambiguous after the word "then" is inserted next to the comma.

Nice answer. Quick question: isn’t it the case that English grammar requires a comma after an independent clause in most cases? I know things have changed since I was in grade school (I’m only 29), but shouldn’t the preferred reading still be OP’s  based off of common comma conventions?

@PW_246 That second reading certainly is contrived (however, I don't think that an independent clause requires a comma after it; for example, the first reading is equally guilty of missing such a comma).

I’m not so sure the first reading needs to comma, since on that reading “If there are berries along the trail, hiking is safe” is not even a clause on the first reading.

@PW_246 In Reading #1, "hiking is safe" is an independent clause, and doesn't require a clause after it. In any case, commas are frequently stylistic, and their absence/presence aren't always conclusively disambiguatory, as is the case here (to be very clear: your contention is that the absence of a comma after the word "safe" rules out Reading 2).

They are not equivalent as they have different truth tables.



p
q
r
r$\rightarrow($q$\iff \lnot$p)
(r$\rightarrow$q)$\iff \lnot$p




0
0
0
0
0


0
0
1
1
1


0
1
0
0
0


0
1
1
0
0


1
0
0
0
1


1
0
1
0
0


1
1
0
0
1


1
1
1
1
1



Your answer says that if bears are in the area and there are no berries, it is still not safe to hike, whereas the official answer says that it is safe to hike (as the bears are in the area but not on the path).


"Your answer says that if bears are in the area and berries aren't ripe, it is still not safe to hike." No: the OP's answer (column 5) in this case makes no assertion about hiking safeness, since it admits both (p,q,r)=(1,0,0) and (p,q,r)=(1,1,0); see rows 5 and 7. $\quad\quad$ 2. "Whereas the official answer says that if bears are in the area and berries aren't ripe, it is safe to hike." No: as explained in my posted answer, the official answer (column 4) in fact forbids this case, since it never admits (p,r)=(1,0); see rows 2 and 8.


Your solution is clearly correct: it is a direct translation of the original statement.
The other solution is incorrect. For example, you could deduce from it the statement $\neg r\to \neg p$ ("if berries are not ripe, bears have not been seen"), since $\neg r \to (r\to q)$. This doesn't follow from the original statement.
